# How to store matched part of regex in python?

Tags: python, regex, loops, string-matching

The string is

```
\xa0\n  xxxxxx\nBirchgrove 101,Durga Saffron Square,\nKariyammana Agrahara, Bellandur,    xxxxxx@xxxxxxx.com\n'
```

and it is in a list called `shipto` and it is at `index 0` of this list.

the regex I am using is

```
shipto_re=re.compile(r"\\n  xxxxxx\\n(.*)(.*?)    xxxxxx")
```

The part of the string that I want is

```
Birchgrove 101,Durga Saffron Square,\nKariyammana Agrahara, Bellandur,
```

How do I iterate through the list `shipto` and store the required regex match in a string variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your actual *text* is

```
 
  xxxxxx
Birchgrove 101,Durga Saffron Square,
Kariyammana Agrahara, Bellandur,    xxxxxx@xxxxxxx.com
```

So, the regex you need may look like

```
\n  xxxxxx\n(.*\n.*)    xxxxxx
\n {2}xxxxxx\n(.*\n.*) {4}xxxxxx
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tsGHvq/1).

See a Python demo below:

```py
import re
shipto=['\xa0\n  xxxxxx\nBirchgrove 101,Durga Saffron Square,\nKariyammana Agrahara, Bellandur,    xxxxxx@xxxxxxx.com\n']
```

Here, I `print`ed the variable to see the literal text:

```py
>>> print(shipto[0])
 
  xxxxxx
Birchgrove 101,Durga Saffron Square,
Kariyammana Agrahara, Bellandur,    xxxxxx@xxxxxxx.com
```

Next:

```py
match = re.search(r'\n {2}xxxxxx\n(.*\n.*) {4}xxxxxx', shipto[0])
if match:
    print(match.group(1))
```

Output:

```
Birchgrove 101,Durga Saffron Square,
Kariyammana Agrahara, Bellandur,
```